# Can you detect how many threads a given number of goroutines will create?

Tags: go, goroutine

I understand that goroutines are multiplexed onto multiple OS threads, so if one should block, such as while waiting for I/O, others continue to run. But is there any way to know ahead of time how many threads I would spawn if I was to create n goroutines?

For example, if we call the function below would we know how many (or the maximum number of) system threads would be created for n goroutines:

```
type Vector []float64

// Apply the operation to n elements of v starting at i.
func (v Vector) DoSome(i, n int, u Vector, c chan int) {
    for ; i < n; i++ {
        v[i] += u.Op(v[i])
    }
    c <- 1;    // signal that this piece is done
}
```

Comment: +1 for one of the only two relevant (non-gossip, non-gee-whiz) GO questions so far

Comment: That's just a for loop.  It doesn't even express concurrency, much less parallelism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Pike's Go Course PDF slides (Day 3):

> ...if you want user-level parallelism you must set `$GOMAXPROCS` or call `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)`. `GOMAXPROCS` tells the runtime scheduler how many non-syscall-blocked goroutines to run at once.

Based on [this blog post](http://grammerjack.blogspot.com/2009/11/multi-threaded-go-raytracer.html), too, it would seem setting the environment variable `GOMAXPROCS` lets you fix the number of threads. I'm not sure how to get the default number of threads the runtime will manage if you do not specify this value, however.

[This blog post](http://kzk9.net/b/2009/11/utilizing-multi-core-in-go-programming-language/) seems to imply that if you do not set the environment variable the runtime will only utilize one core (presumably because it is only using one process.)

Comment: Correction (quote from the spec): "GOMAXPROCS sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing simultaneously and returns the previous setting." If N goroutines are stuck in N system-calls (which require N threads), Go will always have a N+1th thread to reschedule waiting goroutines. Also see http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1644

Answer (score 8):

Each goroutine can use a maximum of one thread at a time. Whether it uses a thread or not depends on what it's doing. The value of GOMAXPROCS determines the number of threads that can be used by freely running Go code - in other words, the maximum level of parallelism.

However more threads can be used, even with GOMAXPROCS=1, when goroutines block directly on system calls or calls into C.

The following operations do *not* cause the goroutine to use a thread when they block:

- channel operations
- network operations
- sleeping
- all primitives in the [sync](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) package

This means, for example, that if you have many goroutines that open /dev/ttyxx and block on read, you'll be using a thread for each one. Same goes if you're execing a load of processes and waiting for them to exit.

Comment: Regarding blocking on /dev/ttyxx, Dmitry Vyukov said in the mailing list: "There is no reason why we can not do "non-blocking under the hoods" handling of files/devices/etc. It's just not done yet. On windows it's easy with IOCP, nonblocking network and file operations are the same. I am not sure what is the state of AIO on unixes today." https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/j51G7ieoKh4/wxNaKkFEfvcJ

Answer (score 3):

Currently, gccgo will create one thread per goroutine.

I don't know about 6g.